# why do my vim macros stop working sometimes?

Tags: vim, macros

This happens to me sometimes, and I haven't been able to figure out why. Lets say I start recording in vim (press q) then I finish and use the macros a few times. Then I do something else, like continue editing the file. Then I want to use the macros again, but this time something else happens, for example, the cursor moves one word backwards.

This has happened to me a few times. For example, today I start a macros (q 2), then I use it (@ 2) a few times. Then I type some text and try to use the macros again (@ 2), but this time the cursor gets moved one word backwards when the macros was supposed to format some text into HTML.

Every time this happens to me I try to reproduce it. I create a dummy macros, then do the same thing again, but I've never been able to reproduce it at will. The macros just works when I try to reproduce this behavior.

I haven't closed or otherwise suspended vim in any of the times this has happened.

I know this question might be hard to respond with the information provided, but I hope this has happened to some of you before and you've been able to figure out why it happens. I'm pretty sure this is just something I don't know about vim.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Numbered registers are used internally by Vim for commands like `y` or `d`.

You shouldn't use them to record your macros as they are overwritten at each yank or delete.

Use registers `a` to `z`, which Vim doesn't touch, instead.

Comment: That sound pretty logical. I'm sure what is happening is exactly what you describe.
Thanks mate.

Comment: This is pretty interesting. It seems like the macros get pussed to the next number. And in fact, an old macros is now on @ 8, when I initially registered it on @ 2. How exactly does this work?

Comment: Each time you `y` or `d` the content of the numbered registers is shifted by one: `"0`'s content becomes `"1`'s content and so on with the last thing you yanked always taking the first register, `"0`. So yeah, it's not really a good idea to save anything there. See `:help registers` for more.